# Get raw ViewState data in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate

I want to get raw `ViewState` data in code behind .
Something like this :

```
private string GetRawViewState()
{
 // What code should be here.
}
// sample result : +9O4aKH/cgkvaOlTP4rWZotoC6yCtEXUhV2khD3IdEcQXc3wwdhiK2oOgWBVYsFmmZc60tR+Vu+XJRi9/9mpzrHbwDuvnq684rT+W8XywFHw2r3KdgVDVPqwHVL3TChORfmaBkcKAYlXf0Fl54PZ/FWfWB96s9fIf4/2iu57Wb0=
```

Comment: Are you asking about the viewstate provided by the client in a postback, or do you want to generate a viewstate from the current control tree?

Comment: second ! I don't want client viewstate(__VIEWSTATE ) . I want to get the Viewstate raw data to be sent to client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no simple way to do this.

It's `internal void Page.RenderViewStateFields(HtmlTextWriter)` that renders the __VIEWSTATE field based on the serialized content in `internal String Page.ClientState { get; set; }`. The serialization is done by [HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Save()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.hiddenfieldpagestatepersister.save(v=vs.110).aspx), but you can only access it via  [Page.PageStatePersister](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.pagestatepersister(v=vs.110).aspx) which is protected.

So, there's no simple api call available for you to do this.

A custom Page class (using [<tagMapping>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228125(v=vs.100).aspx) in web.config) would be able to access things with protected visibility, which means that you can access the PageStatePersister instance, but you do not have access to the serialized value. You could create your own ObjectStateFormatter and serialize the PageStatePersister.ViewState and PageStatePersister.ControlState property, but I am not sure that the values generated will be the same as those sent to the client.

Reflection, on the other hand, can just read the Page.ClientState property. This is available to you in the [Page.SaveStateComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.savestatecomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) event, which occurs after [PageStatePersister.Save()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister.save(v=vs.110).aspx) has been called internally. This is probably the easiest way to do this.